# How to get an RPM's header size and other RPM metadata in linux

Tags: linux, perl, rpm, rpmbuild

Is there a linux command to get the size of header of an RPM? I came across this article that describes the structure of an RPM https://docs.fedoraproject.org/ro/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch-package-structure.html I see there are different tags in RPM metadata and that we can use some languages like C, Perl or Python to read them. If there is no linux command to do it, how to do it using Perl as mentioned in the article above?

Thanks!

Comment: See also [RPM::Header](https://metacpan.org/pod/RPM::Header)

Comment: The above module seems to be abandoned ([last update](https://metacpan.org/release/RJRAY/Perl-RPM-1.51/source/ChangeLog) was in 2007) so it will probably not install on your system. I am looking for alternatives

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Perl module [`RPM::Header::PurePerl`](https://metacpan.org/pod/RPM::Header::PurePerl). Though it was last updated in 2006, so it may not work properly with newer RPM files. For example:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use RPM::Header::PurePerl;

tie my %hdr, "RPM::Header::PurePerl", "sample.rpm" or die "Failed to open rpm file";

say "The following keys can be accessed: ";
say join ",", sort keys %hdr;
say "----------";
say "Example: Version = ", $hdr{VERSION};
```

**Output**:

```
Unknown 2680, 7
Unknown 2730, 6
Unknown 10020, 7
Unknown 10080, 7
Unknown 5011, 4
Unknown 5062, 6
Unknown 5092, 8
Unknown 5093, 4
The following keys can be accessed: 
ARCH,BASENAMES,BUILDHOST,BUILDTIME,CHANGELOGNAME,CHANGELOGTEXT,CHANGELOGTIME,COPYRIGHT,Classdict,DESCRIPTION,DESCRIPTIONLANGS,DIRINDEXES,DIRNAMES,DISTRIBUTION,Dependsdict,FILEDEVICES,FILEFLAGS,FILEGROUPNAME,FILEINODES,FILELANGS,FILELINKTOS,FILEMD5S,FILEMODES,FILEMTIMES,FILERDEVS,FILESIZES,FILEUSERNAME,FILEVERIFYFLAGS,Fileclass,Filedependsn,Filedependsx,GROUP,LEAD_ARCHNUM,LEAD_MAGIC,LEAD_MAJOR,LEAD_MINOR,LEAD_NAME,LEAD_OSNUM,LEAD_RESERVED,LEAD_SIGNATURETYPE,LEAD_TYPE,LICENSE,NAME,OPTFLAGS,OS,PACKAGER,PACKAGE_OFFSET,PAYLOADCOMPRESSOR,PAYLOADFLAGS,PAYLOADFORMAT,PLATFORM,PROVIDEFLAGS,PROVIDENAME,PROVIDES,PROVIDEVERSION,RELEASE,REQUIREFLAGS,REQUIRENAME,REQUIREVERSION,RPMVERSION,SHA1HEADER,SIGMD5,SIGSIZE,SIZE,SOURCERPM,SUMMARY,Sourcepkgid,UNKNOWN1,UNKNOWN2,UNKNOWN4,URL,VENDOR,VERSION
----------
Example: Version = 1.4
```